# How do you say "after all", in the sense of reaffirming or justifying a previous statement?

Tags: word-choice, translation, words, idioms

For example:

- "You should wear a jacket. After all, it's snowing out there."
- "Of course I bought you a present! It's our anniversary after all."

I tried an online dictionary but they gave me a lot of different words. けっきょく seems like a different sort of "after all", more like "in the end." だって seems closest to what I want, but it's listed as a colloquialism and I'd like something more formal. There's しょせん, どうせ, やはり, and それもそのはず, and I'm not sure which if any of them are appropriate.

I've also read だから and なぜなら used in this context being translated as "after all", but is that accurate?

Answer (score 2):

I think for this "after all", your best choice is だって.

> You should wear a jacket. After all, it's snowing out there.
> ジャケット着たほうがいいよ。だって、雪が降っているからね。
>
> Of course I bought you a present! It's our anniversary after all.
> もちろんプレゼント買ってあるよ。だって、俺たちの記念日じゃん。

If you want a formal sentence, I think you should have different example sentences. Especially the second sentence seems to suggest an informal situation.

In a more formal context, you might want to try

- なんでかというと
- なぜかというか
- なぜなら

(increasing order of politeness) to justify a preceding statement.

I would say, though, that a more formal situation would usually imply more careful phrasing, e.g.

> It's snowing outside, so I would suggest you wear a jacket.

And, finally, none of the other options you listed fit this use of "after all". (For what it's worth, I checked an [English dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/after#after__22) and the way you use "after all" in your example sentence is not listed there.)

Comment: だって is arguably not quite the "best" choice though, as using ～だもの sounds at least equally natural in many cases, such as "もちろん、ちょっとしたプレゼントは買ったよ。私たちの記念日だもん。".

Comment: @Will Yeah, sure. I did have なんだもん instead of じゃん in the first sentence (together with だって). I was looking for conjunctions to use at the beginning of the sentence. Why don't you post another answer?

Answer (score 2):

There are no one-to-one translations here. It really depends on who is talking to who and the context of the conversation.

I believe `after all` in these two sentences are similar, but they take slightly different meaning.

The first sentence implies that they were aware of some indications or expectations of snowing. Maybe they had a chat about whether it is going to snow. It is close to saying `You should wear a jacket. After all, it actually snowed (as we expected or didn't expect).`

In the second sentence, the speaker uses `after all` to emphasize the fact that it is their anniversary today.

I would translate these two `after all`s differently in Japanese. Here is my take.

> You should wear a jacket. After all, it's snowing out there.
>
> ジャケット着たほうがいいよ。やっぱり雪降っているし。

`だって` would also work depending on the context, but `やっぱり` sounds more natural to me as it describes a situation that something happened contrary to their expectations.

> Of course I bought you a present! It's our anniversary after all.
>
> もちろんプレゼント買ってあるよ。今日は俺たちの記念日じゃないか。

Using ～じゃないか emphasizes the fact that it is our anniversary. These below may also work. And you can also choose to prefix each of these with なんてったって.

- 今日は俺たちの記念日じゃん。
- 今日は俺たちの記念日でしょう。
- 今日は俺たちの記念日だろ。
- 今日は俺たちの記念日だよ。
- 今日は俺たちの記念日だしね。

Sorry for a very personal answer, but I think it really depends on the context (and also who translates it).